# Setup for Windows Phone 8 Application Development. Error while Making new Project

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone

I have :-

1) Windows 7(64 Bit)

2) Visual Studio 13(Installed)

3) Windows Phone SDK 8.1(Installed)

When I am creating new Mobile project, I am getting Error,

A problem was encountered creating the sub project 'App.Mobile.Native.WinPhone'.  The project file 'C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\us2to0hu.qdd\Temp\App.Mobile.Native.WinPhone.csproj' cannot be opened.

There is a missing project subtype.
Subtype: '{76F1466A-8B6D-4E39-A767-685A06062A39}' is unsupported by this installation.

Please Help.

Comment: Is there any reason you are trying to create a new project in a `temp` folder? Try creating the solution on the Desktop, or in a folder in My Documents?

Comment: @J.B enen on desktop it is giving same error..?

Answer (score 0):

I searched for the Subtype: ‘{76F1466A-8B6D-4E39-A767-685A06062A39}’

It must be Windows Phone 8/8.1 Blank/Hub/Webview App

Refer to:

http://www.codeproject.com/Reference/720512/List-of-Visual-Studio-Project-Type-GUIDs

Please install windows 8.1 SDK from the following link:

https://dev.windows.com/en-us/downloads/sdk-archive

Best Regards,