# Windows Phone 8.1 App Dev - Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone, visual-studio-2015

Currently trying to create a new win phone 8 project within Visual Studio 2015 (Community) and every time i try to create one i get the following error

> There is a missing project subtype
>
> Subtype: {76F1466A-8B6D-A767-685A06062A39} is unsupported by this installation

Also tried creating a universal project with the same error

I'm running Windows 8.1 (64bit) if that makes a difference

Also tried uninstalling and reinstalling all components

[Also tried this thread to no avail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32050704/setup-for-windows-phone-8-application-development-error-while-making-new-projec)

Comment: Might be obvious, but is the SDK installed? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/bg162891.aspx

Comment: @CedricReichenbach it is, but thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end this was solved by refreshing the pc and reinstalling the software. Microsoft support advised to refresh the pc after other attempt by remote failed.

Comment: What do you mean by refreshing the pc ?

Comment: Windows 10 offers an option to refresh the pc as an alternative to rolling back to a previous config